# How to check if cells in different sheets are equal?

Tags: vba, excel, comparison

Scenario: -There are 2 sheets being compared. Range for Sheet1 is B2:B and for Sheet2 is C2:C.

Requirement:

- Sheet1 B2 = Sheet2 C2
- Sheet1 B3 = Sheet2 C3 and so on...

See my existing code below:

```
Sub MessageCode()

    Dim FoundBlank1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range, MyRange2 As Range, MyCell2 As Range

    Set MyRange = ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set MyRange2 = ws2.Range("C2:C" & ws2.Range("C" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set MyCell2 = MyRange2


    For Each MyCell In MyRange

       If MyCell.Value <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value Then

            MyCell.Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
            Set FoundBlank1 = Range("A1:A1000").Find(What:="", lookat:=xlWhole)
            FoundBlank1.Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Incorrect Value."

        End If

    Next MyCell

    End Sub
```

Comment: So, if MyCell.Value <> Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value Then you want to copy the value in Sheet1 and paste it in Sheet2? From what I see I think you're searching for the value of C2 FROM Sheet2 in Sheet1, row 1... and  leave a note saying it's incorrect.... it's kinda confusing for me because you're looking for only row A....  Can you state out what you want so I can try to find a way to help you

Comment: @MT32 If the value for 2 cell are not equal. I will paste it to sheet 3 and with comment beside it "Incorrect values"

Comment: So, sheet 1 and sheet2 will have the same number of rows and column right?

Comment: @MT32, No. Sheet1 and Sheet2 has a column wherein value should be the same or equal. Example. Sheet1 Column A2 should be equal to Sheet2 B2

Comment: Okay. Then Sheet3 is already created, so I dont have to create sheet3 in the code right?

Comment: Also, when you said Sheet1 A2 should equal Sheet2 B2. If they are not equal, you will copy WHICH value to sheet 3?

Comment: please let me know what you wnat to copy. Im almost done with the solution but I have to go for a quick lunch lolll

Comment: In sheet3 A2, B2 of sheet2 should be paste and with comment on B2 of sheet3 "Incorrect value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added in some extra message box if the number of rows of sheet 1 and 2 are not the same.

Try this:

```
Sub Messagecode()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Integer
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
dim lastrow3 as integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
ws1.Activate
lastrow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Activate
lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow1 <> lastrow2 Then
MsgBox ("number of rows in Sheet1 is not equal to number of rows in Sheet2")
End If

For i = 2 To lastrow1
If ws1.Cells(i, 2) <> ws2.Cells(i, 3) Then
ws2.Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

lastrow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lastrow3, 1).Offset(1, 0).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Cells(lastrow3, 1).Offset(1, 1) = "incorrect value"


End If
ws1.Activate

Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the last row for sheet1 and sheet3. run a loop from 2 to the lastrow and compare `Sheet1.columnB` with `Sheet2.columnC` if <> then copy the value in `Sheet1` to `Sheet3`, offset 1 cell to the right and paste your text. You add +1 to the last row in `Sheet3` so you don't keep writing over the same cell...

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Dim lRow3 As Long
lRow3 = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value <> Sheet2.Cells(i, "C").Value Then
            Sheet3.Cells(lRow3, "A").Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value
            Sheet3.Cells(lRow3, "A").Offset(, 1).Value = "Incorrect Value."
        End If
        lRow3 = lRow3 + 1
    Next i
```